# How can I initialize an instance of AttributeCollection?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to initialize an `AttributeCollection` but I seem to get no good suggestions from Google with [this search](https://www.google.se/search?num=20&hl=sv&newwindow=1&safe=off&q=how+to+initialize+%2Battributecollection+componentmodel&oq=how+to+initialize+%2Battributecollection+componentmodel&gs_l=serp.3...97143.97143.0.98116.1.1.0.0.0.0.72.72.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.s5nIKbZ4zQ8).

I'm also open to create the object using the specialized constructor that takes an array of type `Attribute` as described [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.attributecollection.aspx) but I can't find any examples for that either.

I can resolve the issue by adding each attribute on its own as shown below but that's not as nice as initializing it directly.

```
bzzz["prop1"] = "val_1";
bzzz["prop2"] = "val_2";
...
bzzz["prop8"] = "val_8";
bzzz["prop9"] = "val_9";
```

It's the class in `System.ComponentModel`.

Comment: System.ComponentModel? Or System.Web.UI?

Comment: See edit. The article I'm linking to is for `System.ComponentModel` but you can't see it unless you click it. I saw it in the editor and forgot to make the distinction.

Answer (score 5):

This is perfectly legal:

```
var attributes = new AttributeCollection();
attributes.Add("key1", "value1");
attributes.Add("key2", 2);
attributes.Add("key3", new EntityReference("contact", Guid.NewGuid()));

var entity = new Entity(){ Attributes = attributes };
```

### Edit

You can do it all in one C# statement, At one time I saw it as being less readable, but now I see it being more readable so it really comes down to either picking an existing standard, or personal choice:

```
var entity = new Entity()
{
    Attributes = new AttributeCollection() { 
            { "key1", "value1" },
            { "key2", 2 },
            { "key3", new EntityReference("contact", Guid.NewGuid())}
        }
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to initialize the whole shabang at once. I.e. without creating the `attributes` variable before but rather **inside** the initializer? Not that it matters for the code but I'm hugely curious. Thanks for the answer, BTW, mate.

Comment: shorthand is way more readable and usable in lambda loops! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have a simple attribute

```
public class SimpleAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SimpleAttribute(String val)
    {
        value = val;
    }
    protected String value;    
}
```

I would add `Attributes` to the `AttributeCollection` like this.

```
AttributeCollection attrColl = new AttributeCollection(
   new SimpleAttribute("value1"), new SimpleAttribute("value2"));
```

The only constructor parameter is declared as `params`, so you can pass multiple attributes (separated by commas), while you are constructing the collection.

Comment: I don't inherit from `Attribute` class. I'm creating a new instance of `Entity` for CRM Dynamics and in there, I'd like to shove in a new, populated instance of `AttributeCollection`. Is it doable?